# Change a site name or link in the breadcrumb navigation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, breadcrumb

Just enabled the breadcrumb for all team sites however I need to change one of the names found in the drop down.

We recently migrated to 2013 and for some reason it's still showing the old name.

[image]

I need to change the part highlighted in yellow.